# ffmpeg eclipse python mac

Tags: python, eclipse, macos, ffmpeg

Can someone help me with this issue. 
I am doing some python under eclipse, the python library I need use ffmpeg to deal with audio file. 
When I use this library in my ipython console, everything works perfectly but when I use the same code inside eclipse, my program fails to encode the audio file. 
I guess the problem comes from ffmpeg, but I do not know how to solve this.

For information: ffmpeg runs correctly when I call it directly from the command line.

Thank you

Comment: does the call to the library return a value of the logs show anything?

Comment: The solution is to open eclipse through the console, otherwise eclipse does not have the right path

Answer (score 0):

Download the build file from https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/. Put the .exe files in the directory of your project.